# Low-res image when using PHImageManager with fixed width and variable height

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I'm using [Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408) to request images to display in a UIImageView following user-defined parameters.

I'm basically using this code:

```
var options = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersion.Current
options.deliveryMode =  PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormat
options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.Exact
options.networkAccessAllowed = true

PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options: options) { (result: UIImage!, info) -> Void in
    if !info[PHImageResultIsDegradedKey]!.boolValue {
        println("targetSize: \(targetSize)")
        println("asset.pixelWidth: \(asset.pixelWidth)")
        println("asset.pixelHeight: \(asset.pixelHeight)")
        println("result.size: \(result.size)")
    }
}
```

The user can select a "fit-width" or a "fit-height" option. In "fit-width", I use:

```
targetSize = CGSizeMake(width, PHImageManagerMaximumSize.height)
```

while in "fit-height", I use:

```
targetSize = CGSizeMake(PHImageManagerMaximumSize.width, height)
```

where `width` and `height` are obtained dynamically from the UIImageView's dimensions. My thought is that, by using `PHImageManagerMaximumSize` in the non-fixed dimension and `PHImageContentMode.AspectFill` for the `contentMode`, I'll get the largest image possible to fit my UIImageView.

**"Fit-width" option:**

```
targetSize: (2122.40673828125, -1.0)
asset.pixelWidth: 2048
asset.pixelHeight: 1536
result.size: (60.0, 45.0)
```

**"Fit-height" option:**

```
targetSize: (-1.0, 2241.7099609375)
asset.pixelWidth: 2048
asset.pixelHeight: 1536
result.size: (2048.0, 1536.0)
```

The problem happens in the first case: the user is seeing is a very low-res image when using the "fit-width" option.

Am I doing something wrong or is this an issue with PHImageManager?

Comment: Can you show an example of what values are you passing for width and height in fit-width  & fit-height cases respectively?

Comment: Fit-width: (1000.0, -1.0) [conforming to `(width, PHImageManagerMaximumSize.height)`]; 
Fit-height: (-1.0, 1000.0) [conforming to `(PHImageManagerMaximumSize.width, height)`].

Answer (score 1):

Try calling this method synchronously. This will give you the image of the right dimensions and quality straight away. Try this:

```
options.synchronous = true
```